# I've seen threads GO FOR pages and all

Tags: meaning

I am having a little trouble with "go for".

Here's a short explanation: My understanding is that if an user is not posting a log or command output with detailed information, then the threads won't get anywhere because even advanced users either gave no reply at all, or else offered some vague explanations. In other words, ambiguity in replies can extend to several tens of posts in a thread eventually ending when an advanced user may ask relevant specifications and at least give you a hint of what an user is looking for. Or to put it another way, that means when someone is asking these questions, they should post an exact error message and not an interpretation of that message. Doing it this way is necessary for the community to understand the problems that they are dealing with.

Here's the excerpt:
I've seen threads **go for** pages and all someone needed to do was ask for simple command output.

My attempt:
Forum threads that **span** hundreds of pages/That type of thread frequently **extends** across multiple pages...?

Grammatically speaking, does it have something to do with **go long**? Is this sentence grammatically correct, and does it also make sense? I'd like to get the English explanation for that expression in this context. I'm not really sure about that. I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: Forum threads that **go for or run for" hundreds of page. go long is a stock market term. [I would appreciate any help. :)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verb is not "go for", it is "go".  The "for" applies to "pages".

Another  way to write this is to use the verb "to go on" meaning "to continue". This would give

I've seen threads **go on** for pages --->  I've seen threads **continue** for pages

Comment: Excellent! It's exactly what I was thinking about :) <go on too long>

Comment: Of course, the for goes with pages. Run for pages also works.